# Is "ApplicationServices" right name for cross-cutting concerns "stuff"?

Tags: .net, architecture, namespaces, domain-driven-design, naming

I want to find a correct name for my namespace that will contain all projects related to cross-cutting concerns stuff, like logging, security, localization etc.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
CompanyName.ApplicationServices.Logging
CompanyName.ApplicationServices.Security
```

However, what I consider to be an Application Service, doesn't seam to match with DDD definition of Application Service. Thus, I'm not sure that I have chosen the right name for second level namespace...

What do you people think?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have also used the term **infrastructure** loosely for these concerns. I think you need to be careful however. It's better to be specific rather than generic when naming things. Generic containers will be misused and abused. Perhaps it's better to start with two separate namespaces for now and find a meaningful container when you find you know more about a group of related concerns:

```
CompanyName.Logging
CompanyName.Security
```

Striving for reuse too early is dangerous: [Winning is the worst thing that can happen in Vegas](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3384-winning-is-the-worst-thing-that-can-happen-in-vegas)

Answer (score 1):

The services you listed would be categorized as **infrastructure services**. Application services encapsulate your domain and implement use cases by orchestrating repositories, infrastructure services and domain entities.